Error in fitting Zero inflated negative binomial in Python using cross validation
I want to assess predictive power of zero-inflated negative binomial model in Python. My steps are listed as below:
Regarding 5-folds cross-validation:

Fit multiple Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial (ZINB) models on the training data.
Compute the AIC of each model and select the model with the lowest AIC (basing on training dataset).
Once the best model is selected (based on AIC) of training dataset, use it to predict on the test set.
Calculate the Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for that fold.
Calculated Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for all folds

The code is below
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.discrete.count_model import ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP

# Load the dataset
file_path = r'E:\.....'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Define the dependent variable and independent variables
X = data[['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X5']]  # Replace with your actual independent variable column names
y = data['Y']  # Replace with your dependent variable column name

# Add a constant to the independent variables for the intercept
X = sm.add_constant(X)

# Initialize KFold for cross-validation
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# To store the MAE for each fold
mae_scores = []

# Cross-validation loop
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    # Split into train and test
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    
    # Fit the Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial (ZINB) model on the training set
    try:
        zinb_model = ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP(y_train, X_train, exog_infl=X_train).fit()
        zinb_aic = zinb_model.aic
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in fitting model: {e}")
        zinb_aic = np.inf  # Handle any issues during model fitting
    
    # Select the best model with the lowest AIC (we are assuming only one model here)
    best_model = zinb_model
    best_aic = zinb_aic

    # Make predictions on the test set using the best model
    # Ensure that the X_test has the same features as X_train
    try:
        y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)  # Use X_test for prediction
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in prediction: {e}")
        y_pred = np.zeros_like(y_test)  # Default to zero predictions if error
    
    # Calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for the test set
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
    mae_scores.append(mae)

# Calculate the mean MAE across all folds
mean_mae = np.mean(mae_scores)

print(f"Mean Absolute Error (MAE) across all folds: {mean_mae}")

But the error occurs that I do not know the reason
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:1292: OptimizeWarning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
  res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:595: HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
  warnings.warn('Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params '
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:607: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  warnings.warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:1292: OptimizeWarning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
  res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
         Current function value: 2.592112
         Iterations: 35
         Function evaluations: 40
         Gradient evaluations: 40
Error in prediction: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (83,) (21,) 
         Current function value: 2.467550
         Iterations: 35
         Function evaluations: 47
         Gradient evaluations: 47
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:607: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  warnings.warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:1292: OptimizeWarning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
  res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:595: HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
  warnings.warn('Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params '
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:607: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  warnings.warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:1292: OptimizeWarning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
  res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:595: HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
  warnings.warn('Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params '
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:607: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  warnings.warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "
Error in prediction: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (83,) (21,) 
         Current function value: 2.382633
         Iterations: 35
         Function evaluations: 45
         Gradient evaluations: 45
Error in prediction: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (83,) (21,) 
         Current function value: 2.476268
         Iterations: 35
         Function evaluations: 40
         Gradient evaluations: 40
Error in prediction: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (83,) (21,) 
         Current function value: 2.495979
         Iterations: 35
         Function evaluations: 41
         Gradient evaluations: 41
Error in prediction: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (84,) (20,) 
Mean Absolute Error (MAE) across all folds: 5.285714285714286
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_optimize.py:1292: OptimizeWarning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
  res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:595: HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
  warnings.warn('Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params '
C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\ML_241031\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:607: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  warnings.warn("Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to "

Would you please show me my mistake for this! Moreover, I also try to do similar with zero-inflated Poisson regression.
Thanks to comments from  Josef, my model can run. These codes are for doing cross-validation with zero-inflated negative binomial regression (three times of repeating). Anyone finds it useful can use them ^^
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.discrete.count_model import ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP

# Load the dataset
file_path = r'...'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Define the dependent variable and independent variables
X = data[['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6']]
y = data['Y']

# Standardize predictors
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_scaled, columns=X.columns)
X_scaled = sm.add_constant(X_scaled)  # Add constant for intercept

# Number of repetitions for cross-validation
repeats = 3
all_mae_scores = []  # Store MAE scores for all repetitions

for repeat in range(repeats):
    print(f"Starting cross-validation run {repeat + 1}...")
    kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42 + repeat)  # Vary random state for each repetition
    mae_scores = []
    
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_scaled):
        X_train, X_test = X_scaled.iloc[train_index], X_scaled.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        
        # Use a subset of predictors for the inflation component
        X_train_infl = X_train[['X1', 'X2']]
        X_test_infl = X_test[['X1', 'X2']]
        
        try:
            # Fit the model
            zinb_model = ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP(y_train, X_train, exog_infl=X_train_infl).fit(maxiter=1000)
            # Predict on test set
            y_pred = zinb_model.predict(exog=X_test, exog_infl=X_test_infl)
            # Calculate MAE
            mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
            mae_scores.append(mae)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in fold: {e}")
            continue
    
    # Store the mean MAE for this run
    run_mae = np.mean(mae_scores)
    all_mae_scores.append(run_mae)
    print(f"Run {repeat + 1} MAE: {run_mae}")

# Calculate the overall mean MAE across all repetitions
final_mean_mae = np.mean(all_mae_scores)
print(f"Mean MAE across all runs: {final_mean_mae}")

Moreover, these codes are not necessary if you find your model OK with no problem (I think that would please correct if I am wrong)
# Standardize predictors
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_scaled, columns=X.columns)
X_scaled = sm.add_constant(X_scaled)  # Add constant for intercept
```


predict also needs exog_infl.  predict does not know exog_infl for out of sample prediction. (But the shape mismatch looks larger than missing exog_infl number of columns.)

For optimization failures: you need to check that each fold has data that are well conditioned (e.g. no nearly perfect collinearity) and has zero-inflation, and overdispersion relative to Poisson. ZINB will fail to converge if there is no zero inflation and all NB models will fail if there is no over dispersion. (Also reusing start_params might help.)

@Josef thank you for your comment !!! it works

You seem to have solved your problem, then you can answer your own question, so it does not linger on as unresolved
